# I executed selenium code but an error is appearing

Tags: java, selenium

Using this script but an error message appears.

```
WebElement elecounty = (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='select_county']//span[text()='select'] ")));
//Thread.sleep(5000);
elecounty.click();Thread.sleep(5000);
elecounty.sendKeys("Baker");
```

Error message:

```
element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.142)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'NAV-L186', ip: '192.168.0.186', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_212'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 75.0.3770.142, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 75.0.3770.90 (a6dcaf7e3ec6f..., userDataDir: ...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:58326}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: d287681e8c023df5adc766bffc9d5b15
```

Comment: Post your relevant html for better clarity about elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ElementNotInteractableException is thrown to indicate that although an element is present with in the HTML DOM, it is not in a state that can be interacted with.

You should use `WebDriverWait` with  [ExpectedCondition.elementToBeClickable](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable-org.openqa.selenium.By-):

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement elecounty = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='select_county']//span[text()='select']")));
elecounty.click();
```

Comment: executed above you send me  but i am send some values so again above error message is appearing. through sendkey

Comment: @zafarahmad you should be using `WebDriverWait` for all actions you do... that's why I put the `wait` var... you can learn more about [WebDriverWait here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html)